# suppress wxFileName::Normalize error messages

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, filepath

I have the following `c++` code that used to normalize user supplied file path:

```
wxString orig_path;      
wxFileName res_path(orig_path);
res_path.Normalize(wxPATH_NORM_DOTS);
```

***Refs:***

[wxFileName::Normalize](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_name.html#a2db3fcc42863daa265619de0d5f390df)
[wxFileName::Normalize flags](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/filename_8h.html#a18dd81e40b3fad4a089077e28e5dce22)

When:

```
orig_path = "../../dir1/f.csv"
```

I get annoying error messages:

```
Error: The path 'f.csv' contains too many ".."!
```

When:

```
orig_path = "dir1/../dir2/f.csv"
```

everything works as expected.

#### Question

Any way I can suppress those error messages? (silent flag?).
I guess I can do some processing myself before calling `Normailze` but what's the point? I prefer not to do anything or know anything about `orig_path` before calling `Normailze`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `wxLogNull`. All calls to the log functions during the life time of an object of this class are just ignored.
See [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_log_null.html).

```
wxLogNull noLogsPlease;
wxString orig_path;      
wxFileName res_path(orig_path);
res_path.Normalize(wxPATH_NORM_DOTS);
```

Comment: by the way, how can I restore logging for the rest of function execution? I guess this object need to be destroyed.

Comment: Put the part inside { }. As soon as you get out of that piece of code, this local object will be destroyed and your logging will be resumed. Check the first example in documentation.